# Ads failing to load

Tags: android, ads

> ```
>  Starting ad request.
>    09-16 09:31:56.827 9836-9836/com.netvariant.panic I/Ads: Use    
>    AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("F92724BDB6A4403A8C027B851F7DA3AF")   
>    to get    test ads on this device.
>    09-16 09:31:58.385 9836-9849/com.netvariant.panic I/Ads: No fill 
>     from ad server.
>    09-16 09:31:58.392 9836-9836/com.netvariant.panic W/Ads: Failed to load ad: 3
> ```

Am getting this error in my xml:

> ```
>  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
>    <RelativeLayout     
>  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
> xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
> xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
> android:id="@+id/tesd"
> android:layout_width="match_parent"
> android:layout_height="match_parent">
> <com.google.android.gms.ads.doubleclick.PublisherAdView
>     android:id="@+id/ad_view"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
>     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
>     ads:adSize="BANNER"
>     ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-4532549351948034/7622739505" />
>    </RelativeLayout>
> ```

And my java code is:

> ```
>  mAdView = (PublisherAdView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.ad_view);
>         // Create an ad request. Check logcat output for the hashed   
>         device ID to
>         // get test ads on a physical device. e.g.
>         // "Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("ABCDEF012345") to 
>         get test ads on this device."
>         PublisherAdRequest adRequest = new   
>         PublisherAdRequest.Builder().build();
>         // Start loading the ad in the background.
>         mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
> ```

And this is how am loading it. What is the problem? Thank You.I created firebase, and admob accounts using my Mac sha1 ( not keystore that i use to upload on store).am running from my android studio to device, its not working.I have google-services.json in my app too.

I followed this instructions

```
[https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/][1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like it said in the logcat console, you need to add the following line to your code block where you initiate the ads.

```
AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("F92724BDB6A4403A8C027B851F7DA3AF");
```

This helps Google Ads know that you are testing the ads function on an emulator and return a test ads. The reason for this is to make sure developers won't click on the ads (by accident) while testing which may result in your ads account being banned, and also, other apps running on actual devices are served with real ads.

Comment: what if when i upload it on store, will it work without the addtestdevice part?

Comment: Two things you can do when it is time for you to publish your app 1) Either comment out that line or 2) Adding in a variable to check whether you are in development mode or production mode.